# Tagit not apending values inside the text box when on button click

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I have two text boxes and one button. The user will enter the text and click the add button. This will add and a tag with the value to another text box, actually it is tagging the first value but it is not appending the other values which is coming from the text box what may be the problem. It is the code which I tried for your reference:

```
<div class=""> <input name = "DynamicTextBox" class="my_txt"  id="text1" type="text"/><a href="#" id="Save" class="addTime">Add</a><input type="text" id="text2" class="tarea" /></div>'

$('#Save').click(function () {
    $('#text2').val($('#text2').val() + $('#text1').val() + ',');
    $('#text2').tagit();
})
```

Comment: add all relevant code to OP. Add html as well

Comment: please check the code now